# Spring Framework JpaRepository returns duplicates of first table row by findAll() method

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

Here is my **JpaRepository**

```
public interface ProcessorRepository extends JpaRepository<Processor, Integer> {
}
```

**Controller**

```
...
@Autowired
ProcessorRepository processorRepository;

@RequestMapping("/getAll")
public String showAllProcessors(Map map){

    List<Processor> processorList = processorRepository.findAll();

    map.put("processors", processorList);
    return "main";
}
```

**main.jsp**

```jsp
....
<select>
<option selected="selected">Choose Processor</option>
<c:forEach var="proc" items="${processors}">
    <option>
            ${proc.processorName}
    </option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

This is how Processor mysql table looks like:

[image: Processor table]

---

But this is what I get

[image]

Why it returns duplicates of first row, instead of all different rows?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out the problem was in my Processor entity. It had @Column(name="id") instead of @Column(name="processor_id").

Comment: Firstly I had a id field in my Model and then I changed it in database but I did not changed it in my code. This was the cause why it is returning the same duplicate list.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a `custom method` in the `repository` to return `Distinct` values

```
List<Processor> findDistinctProcessorsByprocessorName();
```

in the above method `processorName` will be taken as the propety to find the duplicates you can change it if you want to.